# Using @Autowired with AspectJ and Springboot

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, autowired, spring-boot

I want to use @Autowired annotation into an "Aspect". I want to inject a repository in my aspect but when I try to call a method of my autowired class a NullPointException occurs.

```
@Aspect
public class AspectSecurity {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@After("execution(public * dash.*.*Controller.*(..))")
public void authentication(JoinPoint jp) throws UnauthorizedException {
    System.out.println("SECURITY !");

    System.out.println(userRepository.findAll().toString());

   }
}
```

I have already tried to add `@Component` above my aspect Class but I have the same error.

If I don't use an aspect class but a `@Controller` I can call my repository without problems.

Some documentation speak about spring configuration with xml files but with spring boot I don't have these files.

Here a part of my pom.xml which calls the aspectJ plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>${compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Here my Application class:

```
package dash;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here the Controller class which the aspect is called:

```
package dash.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import dash.GenericController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends GenericController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@RequestMapping("/findAll")
public @ResponseBody User create(
        @RequestParam(value="login", required=true) String login,
        @RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password) {
    
    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println(password);
    

    System.out.println("Users found with findAll():");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    for (User user : repository.findAll()) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
    
    
    return  repository.findOne("root");
    }
}
```

Note: I have already tried to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` above my application class.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the Aspect?

Comment: Have you tried adding `@Configurable` to the aspect class?

Comment: The aspect is used "after" the "create" method. There is no logical naming. It's just a POC. According to the aspect expression `@After("execution(public * dash.*.*Controller.*(..))")` the aspect is called for all public methods having "Controller" at the end of the name in all classes of all packages of the package "dash" ^^

Comment: I juste tried to add `@Configurable` above the declaration of my aspect class but I have the same result. Could you give me some explanations about why you want to add @Configurable ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's quite tricky to set up AspectJ weaving so a few things could be wrong here. I would suggest that you do *not* use `@Component` on your `@Aspect` (or at least make sure it is excluded from a `@ComponentScan`). The reason for that is you have to create a `@Bean` of that type and explicitly use the same creation mechanism that AspectJ does, so that Spring and AspectJ agree on the value of the singleton instance. I believe the correct way to do that is to use the static convenience methods in `Aspects` in your `@Bean` definition.  E.g.

```
@Bean
public AspectSecurity interceptor() {
    AspectSecurity aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(AspectSecurity.class);
    // ... inject dependencies here if not using @Autowired
    return aspect;
}
```

In addition you will need an `aop.xml` to ensure that the compiled aspect is on the AspectJ weaver path. It could be that is what you are doing with the Maven AspectJ plugin, but if it was me doing this I would probably just create an `aop.xml` manually, use `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`, and ditch the plugin.  You can probably decide yourself based on what works.

There can also be lifecycle issues if the aspect needs to intercept something that is used during the construction of the application context. You can maybe avoid that by not relying on any interception in `@Bean` methods, or else you end up playing games with `@DependsOn` to try and force a particular order of bean creation. Whether your app suffers from that yet I can't say.

PREVIOUSLY (obsolete with Spring Boot 1.3):

Another stumbling block is that you are using Spring Boot and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which explicitly switches on `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, and that switches off the AspectJ weaving for the Spring bean aspects. I actually have no idea if that is an intended side effect of `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, but you can disable it by excluding it from the autoconfig, e.g.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=AopAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {    
    ...
}
```

N.B. you might not notice that weaving is switched off if you forget to exclude this config because Spring will create proxies for you and many of your aspects will just work anyway.

Comment: Instead of exclude AopAutoConfiguration, you could also configure: `spring.aop.auto=false`

Answer (score -1):

Here is my configuration:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class WebControllerAop {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;
    //匹配com.zkn.learnspringboot.web.controller包及其子包下的所有类的所有方法
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.zkn.learnspringboot.web.controller..*.*(..))")
    public void executeService(){

    }
}

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class FirstExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstExample.class, args);
    }
}

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

It can work well.